# 5 GHz wifi speed?

Tags: wifi, wireless, wireless-adapter

Has anybody else experienced very slow 5 GHz speed ? Mine times out most of the time and the router is 5 m distant. 2.4 GHz works better but it is saturated where I live and I cannot use it for streaming as it constantly buffers. At the moment I have to use EoP devices so I can get Ethernet speeds.
Wondering if it is the integrated 5 GHz that’s not good and I’m better off buying an external dongle?

This is the iperf3 result between RPi and Mac on 5 GHz:

```
[  5]   0.00-1.00   sec  12.6 MBytes   106 Mbits/sec                  
[  5]   1.00-2.00   sec  16.2 MBytes   136 Mbits/sec                   
[  5]   2.00-3.00   sec  17.0 MBytes   143 Mbits/sec                               [  5]   8.00-9.00   sec  17.2 MBytes   144 Mbits/sec                   
[  5]   9.00-10.00  sec  17.5 MBytes   147 Mbits/sec                   
[  5]  10.00-10.03  sec   813 KBytes   197 Mbits/sec                   - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - [  5]   0.00-10.03  sec   169 MBytes   141 Mbits/sec
```

Not sure if it looks ok but I think so. How can I run iperf3 to my router?

Comment: is that 5m clear line of sight? or are there some walls, furniture or Faraday cages in the way?

Comment: @JaromandaX just a wall with the door. I have two computers in that room, tv and Playstation all connected to 5ghz no issues, RPi is the only one that times out or uses ridiculous speed like a 56k dial up modem.

Comment: What OS? How is networking configured? How did you test? What speed do you get?

Comment: @Milliways raspbian OS. Speedtest.net for the tests. It gives me 0.2mbps in download and 0.1 in upload. On Ethernet it give me 49.3 Mbps speed. How is it configured? Turned on wifi, selected 5ghz from the list and put my password in, that’s how it’s done on all my computers, phone, tablet, ps4

Comment: Raspbian is MEANINGLESS - it could be any of 5 families of OS spanning 10 years.
Even Raspberry Pi OS is ambiguous - at last count there are 8 and there are significant differences between Buster & Bullseye.

Comment: Also which model of Pi?

Comment: Speedtest DOES NOT test your WiFi - it tests your router + ISP's network. If you want to measure WiFi try `iperf3` to a local client.

Comment: Pi 4 rasp os buster. I’m not testing my router wifi, i know it works fine on 7/8 devices, it’s rpi that refuses to work. And tried with two different routers, one is the provider one and the second is newly acquired Eero. Same speed. What i am testing is wireless communication between pi and router. Will try iperf3

Comment: Your OS is out of date for a start. Flash another sd card with Raspberry Pi OS Bullseye and fully update. Update your question with all the details you have added.

Comment: @CoderMike this is not that makes it go slow as I’ve had this problem for a year and bullseye wasn’t even out yet. I’ve just decided to see what’s the issue is only now.

Comment: @Kerberos there may be a fix in the latest Bullseye that solves your issue. People are unlikely to help unless you are using the very latest updated OS.

Comment: @CoderMike Buster IS supported (called Legacy) and it should have identical firmware (if updated). IMO it is more reliable than the incomplete Bullseye release.

Answer (score 0):

Internet speed tests are not a reliable indicator as there are too many links in the chain.

I use `iperf3` (which is in the repository and also available for other platforms).

Testing from a Pi3+ to a Pi4 (connected via Gigabit Ethernet) I get for 5GHz and 2.4GHz

```
    [ ID] Interval           Transfer     Bitrate         Retr
    [  5]   0.00-10.00  sec  58.6 MBytes  49.2 Mbits/sec    8             sender
    [  5]   0.00-10.02  sec  58.1 MBytes  48.7 Mbits/sec                  receiver

    [ ID] Interval           Transfer     Bitrate         Retr
    [  5]   0.00-10.00  sec  27.5 MBytes  23.1 Mbits/sec   14             sender
    [  5]   0.00-10.03  sec  26.8 MBytes  22.5 Mbits/sec                  receiver
```

You can check performance with `ip -s a` which will show

```
    RX: bytes  packets  errors  dropped missed  mcast   
    125439060  148925   0       0       0       2394    
    TX: bytes  packets  errors  dropped carrier collsns 
    184479938  161571   0       0       0       0
```

This gives an indication of problems.

The first step should be to check (and if necessary change) what mode & channel the router is set to. Select a channel other than the default often improves performance and the widest bandwidth often does not perform at highest speed, particularly if there is interference.

Comment: This is the iperf3 result between RPi and Mac on 5Ghz:

`[  5]   0.00-1.00   sec  12.6 MBytes   106 Mbits/sec                  
[  5]   1.00-2.00   sec  16.2 MBytes   136 Mbits/sec                  
[  5]   2.00-3.00   sec  17.0 MBytes   143 Mbits/sec                             
[  5]   8.00-9.00   sec  17.2 MBytes   144 Mbits/sec                  
[  5]   9.00-10.00  sec  17.5 MBytes   147 Mbits/sec                  
[  5]  10.00-10.03  sec   813 KBytes   197 Mbits/sec                  
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
[  5]   0.00-10.03  sec   169 MBytes   141 Mbits/sec`

Comment: Do NOT post detail in Comments - edit your Question.