# Pi 4b Ethernet Connection Reports 1000mbps, but All Browser's Website Speed Tests report 150mbps Download Speed

Tags: ethernet, web-browsers

My Raspberry Pi 4b Ethernet Connection Reports 1000mbps, but All Browser's Website Speed Tests report 150mbps Download Speed.

I am not using WiFi.  All internet connections are Cat6 direct ethernet.

I am not using SD cards, I am using USB 3.0 port Samsung 64 Gig Flash drives.

I tried both Raspbian and Windows 10 and both are about 8X too slow in the browser no matter what browser I use on either platform.

I tried to troubleshoot the problem in Raspbian with this command.

pi@raspberry:~ $ sudo ethtool eth0 | grep Speed

Speed: 1000Mb/s

As you can see the speed is reported at 1000mbps. The ethernet cable connector LEDs are solid orange and flashing green.  Flashing green indicates a 1 gig connection.

I have no GPIO code running or any scripts just clean OS installs for Raspbian and Windows 10

I performed the following to update the OS

sudo rpi-eeprom-update -a (eeprom was one month out of date and now it's the newest)

sudo apt update

sudo apt full-upgrade

When I launch any browser and do a speed test using the sites listed below, all are about the same, incredibly slow!

I tried the following sites to test:

https://www.verizon.com/speedtest/

https://www.speedtest.net/

https://www.att.com/support/speedtest/

Is this normal? I can't even stream a YouTube video, it will buffer indefinitely.  Web pages will load very slow and I can access some streaming live radio web pages without buffering.

Comment: The speedtest may be writing to the sd card - which is slow. https://forums.raspberrypi.com/viewtopic.php?t=261016

Comment: I am not using SD cards, I am using USB Samsung 64 Gig Flash drives

Comment: What is the write speed on your flash drive? What is your broadband speed?

Comment: I thought it was 400mb/s but after checking it is only 150mb/s. It looks like you hit the nail on the head.  I just ordered 2 more flash disks from Amazon, they will be here by the weekend and I will see if that does the trick.  I'm sure it will.  I ordered 2 Samsung https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B07BPKKTGL/ref=ppx_yo_dt_b_asin_title_o00_s00?ie=UTF8&psc=1  I can't find any faster unless I move to an M.2 or something

Comment: The speed limitation could very likely be your internet connection as well. So if you get a faster flash drive, that may bump you up in speed but an internet speed test won't go any faster than your connection pipe size. Do you have gigabit internet?

Comment: Yes, Verizon Fios https://www.verizon.com/speedtest/ clocks in at Router: 949mbps download and 941mbps upload, the Raspberry Pi Device: 56mbps Download and 23mbps Upload on the pi running Window 10. I just now ran the speed test.

Comment: Same test as above using Raspbian OS from 150mb/s SD Card. verizon.com/speedtest reports; Router: 927mbps Download, 941mbps Upload; Raspberry Pi Device: 139mbps Download and 52mbps Upload. I couldn't test USB Flash at this time.

Comment: I'm thinking maybe stick with Raspbian and a new 400mb/s USB.  I wanted to use Windows 10 so I can use Visual Studio C# and the NAudio Nuget for my GPIO audio monitoring project arm64.  I might have to figure out if Python can give me what NAudio does providing Audio Peak detection.  Based on the above tests, do you think the speed might be solved with Raspbian 400mbps USB drive?

Answer (score 0):

Browser speed tests are not meaningful (unless you are testing your ISP) Use `iperf3` to test interface performance.
See https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/138436/8697

Answer (score 0):

You are troubleshooting two different issues.

The webpages loading slowly and YouTube videos buffering indefinitely can be a different issue from the Pi's ability to push data. (a myriad of other services can fail and deliver sluggish performance)

That being said, the theoretical limit of 1000mbps is not really realistic in real life.
One way to test it, (apart from the iperf3 solution) is to connect both your PC and Pi to the same router via the 1 Gbps port and setup a decent sharing between the two.

Push a file from the router/NAS/PC to the PI over the 1 Gbps connection and check it's speed. For me, it's easily around the 500-700 Mbps with Raspbian running on a good SSD.